# MySQL select statement, query across 2 tables where 1 column matches

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following MySQL

```
    $tutorial = $database->query(
        'SELECT ' . 
            'tutorial.*, ' . 
            'apps.*'.
                'FROM ' . 
                    $database->db_prefix . 'tutorial, ' . 
                    $database->db_prefix . 'apps ' . 
                        'WHERE ' .
                            'apps.title = "' . $name . '" AND apps.id = tutorial.app AND tutorial.relation = "' . $user['id'] . '"'
    );
```

I want to get the row where apps.title is equal to $name and then get all tutorials based on that retrieved apps id. This acts as a link between the two tables.

Is the above going to work?

in particular:

```
'apps.title = "' . $name . '" AND apps.id = tutorial.app AND tutorial.relation = "' . $user['id'] . '"'
```

Comment: You **really** need to read up on how to properly [escape SQL parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This is dangerously insecure.

Comment: ay? how is this dangerously insecure lmao? $name contains a posted variable that i have validated. :s don't be silly.

Comment: Validation is not sufficient. You **must** escape any and all values you are putting into your SQL. If it's not obvious it's escaped, you're doing it wrong. If you take a casual approach, you will get burned. You won't be laughing when someone with an [automatic injection tool](http://sqlmap.org/) hijacks your site.

Comment: so the fact that my $name is escaped further up in my code doesn't mean anything? lol. I can send you  the whole php script if you want... it won't fit here though ;)

Comment: In stackoverflow you are required to present short bits of code specific to your question. I think you're going to have to understand this in the future.. as you can see I haven't included the declaration of $name in my code as it is not necessary for this question.

Comment: If you do ad-hoc escaping like this, where some values are prepared in advance and others may not be, you're playing with fire and you will get burned. The safe way to be sure it's escaped is to use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/) like `?` or `:name` depending on your interface. String concatenation is inherently hazardous.  `title='$name'` *might* be escaped, but `title=?` means it's obviously escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the row where apps.title is equal to $name and then get
>   all tutorials based on that retrieved apps id.

From the query you posted above, I think you can `JOIN` the two tables using the `app` field something like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tutorials t 
INNER JOIN apps a ON t.app = a.app
WHERE a.title = $name AND t.relation = $user['id']
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
  tutorial.*
FROM tutorial
WHERE toutorial.app IN
(
    SELECT app FROM apps WHERE apps.title = $name AND app IS NOT NULL
) AND tutorial.relation = $user['id']
```

Comment: Genius :D, the second one works great!!

Is there any benefit to using join?

Comment: @JamesT - Yes, in case you want to select more rows from the second joined table and other benefits. Not that when using `IN` watch out the `NULL` values of the `app` values coming from `apps` table. If there is one `app` with `NULL` value, thats why I added `IS NOT NULL` in my edit, your query won't return any thing. `JOIN` is safe and I think in most cases is faster.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not going to work. See the Mysql [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax.